# 'return false' doesn't end my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The 2nd bracket in my `verifyImageURL()` definately triggers as the console logs `no`.

However, `return false` doesn't end the function. Everything continues on after that (the AJAX call at the end fires).

Here's my JS:

```
function verifyImageURL(url, callBack) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  img.onload = function () {
        callBack(true);
  };
  img.onerror = function () {
        callBack(false);
  };
}

$('input#id_imageURL').on('change', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).val();
    console.log(url, url['type']);
    verifyImageURL(url, function (imageExists) {
        if (imageExists === true) {
            console.log('yes');
        } else {
            console.log('no');
            $('.add_file_div h3').html('That URL is not an image');
            return false;
        }
    });

    var formData = new FormData();
    var random_filename = random_string();

    if ( validateYouTubeUrl($(this).val()) ) {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var videoid = url.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/);
        $('.add_file_label').append('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoid[1] + '"' + '</iframe>');
        $('.add_file_div h3').hide();
        $('.add_file_label').css({
            'border-radius': '5px',
            'box-shadow': '5px',

        });
        $('input#id_imageURL').hide();
        $('#delete_preview_image').show();
    }
    else {

        $('.add_file_div h3').hide();
        $('.add_file_label').css({
            'border-radius': '5px',
            'box-shadow': '5px',
        });
        var imagePath = e.currentTarget.value;
        $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
        $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '0.4');
        $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('.add_file_label').append('<input class="temp_s3_url" type="hidden" name="temp_s3_url">');
        $('.temp_s3_url').val(random_filename);
        $('input#id_imageURL').hide();
        $('#delete_preview_image').show();


        formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val());
        formData.append('random_filename', random_filename);
        formData.append('imageURL', imagePath);

        console.log('Entered:', imagePath);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/upload_image/',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
                $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '1');
                $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
                $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        });

    }
});
```

and idea what the problem is?

Comment: It does end the function, but only the anonymous callback you're passing to `verifyImageURL`. Put everything after `verifyImageURL` in a separate function and call it when `imageExists === true`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following code will work, it uses verifyImageUrl as a promise:

```
function verifyImageURL(url) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve){
      img.onload = function () {
        resolve(true);
      };
      img.onerror = function () {
        resolve(false);
      };    
    }
  )
}

$('input#id_imageURL').on('change', function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var url = $this.val();
  console.log(url, url['type']);
  verifyImageURL(url)
  .then(function (imageExists) {
    if (imageExists === true) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
      $('.add_file_div h3').html('That URL is not an image');
      return false;
    }

    var formData = new FormData();
    var random_filename = random_string();

    if (validateYouTubeUrl($this.val())) {
      console.log($this.val());
      var videoid = url.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/);
      $('.add_file_label').append('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoid[1] + '"' + '</iframe>');
      $('.add_file_div h3').hide();
      $('.add_file_label').css({
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'box-shadow': '5px',

      });
      $('input#id_imageURL').hide();
      $('#delete_preview_image').show();
    }
    else {

      $('.add_file_div h3').hide();
      $('.add_file_label').css({
        'border-radius': '5px',
        'box-shadow': '5px',
      });
      var imagePath = e.currentTarget.value;
      $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
      $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '0.4');
      $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('.add_file_label').append('<input class="temp_s3_url" type="hidden" name="temp_s3_url">');
      $('.temp_s3_url').val(random_filename);
      $('input#id_imageURL').hide();
      $('#delete_preview_image').show();


      formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val());
      formData.append('random_filename', random_filename);
      formData.append('imageURL', imagePath);

      console.log('Entered:', imagePath);
      return $.ajax({
        url: '/upload_image/',
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
      }).then(
        function () {
          $('.add_file_label').css('opacity', '1');
          $('.add_file_label').css('background', 'url(' + imagePath + ') scroll no-repeat center/cover');
          $('.loading_spinner').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
      );
    }
  }).catch(
    function(error){
      console.error("There was an error:",error);
    }
  );
});
```

Your function seems to be a bit long, maybe you should split it up in smaller functions like `hideFileInput`.